# iPhone - UITableView to DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a `tableView` which lists the contents directory which includes jpg and mp4 files.

Currently when you select any mp4 file it loads the `MPMovieController` and plays the correct file accordingly however I am unsure on how to load a detailed view if the extension of the file is a JPG.

For example if the selected file in the `tableView` is a image file, it opens an `imageView` in the `detailView` to display that image.

For other files, it pushes an `alertView` regarding that it is an unknown file.

This is the code i have so far for the `tableview didSelectRowAtIndex`

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.1.4.3:8080/DCIM/DCIM/VIDEO/%@",[movieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

//Play multiple video
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];}
```

Any links or source code would be very handy.

Thanks.

Comment: That means you are do not know what type of file a cell can contain at the time of loading the cell?

Comment: @RatikantaPatra the cells are displaying correctly and the mp4 files are loading however I need it to go to a detailedView when JPG is selected.

Comment: You need to have your own customised detailed view which would contain an imageView inside to hold the corresponding JPG image.

Comment: Okay, then once that is set up how do I check to see what extension is being selected, say if mp4 load the moviePlayer and if the cell is a JPG load the detailed view? @RatikantaPatra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this code because I did not have time

however, it should work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    /* ============================== THIS DO THE TRICK ============================ */
    NSString *kind = nil;
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.1.4.3:8080/DCIM/DCIM/VIDEO/%@", [movieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString *ext = [[path pathExtension] lowercaseString];

    if([ext isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"png"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        UIViewController *imageController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]]];

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        [imageController.view setFrame:frame];
        [imageView setFrame:frame];
        [imageController.view addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

        [self presentModalViewController:imageController animated:TRUE];

        [imageController release];
    }
    /* ============================================================================= */
    else {
        NSString *urlString = path;

        //Play multiple video
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                         initWithContentURL:url];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:_moviePlayer];

        _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
        [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: add an extension type in the IF condition if you want to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use MPMoviePlayerController, so that xcode will handle your file (it will create view which play movie and dismiss view after finish).

If you want to show your image, just create your custom view with close button (cause you will need to dismiss your view). In this custom view, add an UIImageView and show your image.

Comment: Can you provide any tutorials or source code that does this? @dementiazz